# Add a column in a group by function and not use it as group by column in dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm fairly new to DAX and got stuck in a variable that requires me to show a column but not group by it,for example what I need to understand is the following

```
GROUPBY(
SELECTCOLUMNS(
NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN ( join_old_tables, calculated_join ),
"val1",[val1],
"val2",[val2],
"val3",[val3],
"val4",[val4],
),
[val1],
[val2],
"val3",SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(),[val3])
)
```

and add val4 so that I can see it in the table but not use it as a groupby column

Thank you

EDIT1 :  [this is the table where I need to add a column and not group by it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrBVp.png)

the code that I used is the following

```
VAR Rq_Diagnostic_3 =
        GROUPBY (
            SELECTCOLUMNS (
                NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN ( joint_old_tables, calculated_jointure ),
                "PERIODE_REP_ID", [PERIODE_REP_ID],
                "AGENCE_ID", [AGENCE_ID],
                "IMMEUBLE_ID", [IMMEUBLE_ID],
                "Libellé Immeuble", [Libellé Immeuble],
                "Nombre_Lot", [nombre_Lot],
                "Nombre immeuble", [Nombre immeuble],
                "Regroupement 2", [Regroupement 2],
                "IMMEUBLE_SURF", [IMMEUBLE_SURF],
                "SURF_AUDITEE", [SURF_AUDITEE],
                "DPE_MONTANT", [DPE_MONTANT],
                "DPE_INDIC", [DPE_INDIC],
                "GES_MONTANT", [GES_MONTANT],
                "GES_INDIC", [GES_INDIC],
                "CODE_DPE",
                    IF (
                        AND ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE] >= 0, [Niveau_Moy_DPE] < 20 ),
                        MID ( "A", 1, 10 ),
                        IF (
                            AND ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE] > 50, [Niveau_Moy_DPE] <= 91 ),
                            MID ( "B", 1, 10 ),
                            IF (
                                AND ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE] > 91, [Niveau_Moy_DPE] <= 151 ),
                                MID ( "C", 1, 10 ),
                                IF (
                                    AND ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE] > 151, [Niveau_Moy_DPE] <= 231 ),
                                    MID ( "D", 1, 10 ),
                                    IF (
                                        AND ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE] > 231, [Niveau_Moy_DPE] <= 331 ),
                                        MID ( "E", 1, 10 ),
                                        IF (
                                            AND ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE] > 331, [Niveau_Moy_DPE] <= 451 ),
                                            MID ( "F", 1, 10 ),
                                            IF (
                                                AND ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE] > 451, [Niveau_Moy_DPE] <= 531 ),
                                                MID ( "G", 1, 10 ),
                                                IF (
                                                    [Niveau_Moy_DPE] > 531,
                                                    MID ( "H", 1, 10 ),
                                                    MID ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE], 1, 20 )
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                "Niveau_Moy_DPE", [Niveau_Moy_DPE],
                "CODE_GES",
                    IF (
                        AND ( [Niveau_Moy_GES] >= 0, [Niveau_Moy_GES] <= 5 ),
                        MID ( "A", 1, 10 ),
                        IF (
                            AND ( [Niveau_Moy_GES] > 5, [Niveau_Moy_GES] <= 11 ),
                            MID ( "B", 1, 10 ),
                            IF (
                                AND ( [Niveau_Moy_GES] > 11, [Niveau_Moy_GES] <= 21 ),
                                MID ( "C", 1, 10 ),
                                IF (
                                    AND ( [Niveau_Moy_GES] > 21, [Niveau_Moy_GES] <= 35 ),
                                    MID ( "D", 1, 10 ),
                                    IF (
                                        AND ( [Niveau_Moy_GES] > 35, [Niveau_Moy_GES] <= 51 ),
                                        MID ( "E", 1, 10 ),
                                        IF (
                                            AND ( [Niveau_Moy_GES] > 51, [Niveau_Moy_GES] <= 80 ),
                                            MID ( "F", 1, 10 ),
                                            IF (
                                                [Niveau_Moy_GES] > 80,
                                                MID ( "G", 1, 10 ),
                                                MID ( [Niveau_Moy_GES], 1, 20 )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                "Niveau_Moy_GES", [Niveau_Moy_GES],
                "Total(IMMEUBLE_SURF)", [IMMEUBLE_SURF],
                "Total(Nombre_Lot)", [Nombre_Lot],
                //"Total(SURF_AUDITEE)", [SURF_AUDITEE],
                "Moy_Niv_Moy_DPE", ( [DPE_MONTANT] / [Nombre immeuble] ),
                "Donnée élémentaire4",
                    IF (
                        AND ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE] >= 0, [Niveau_Moy_DPE] < 20 ),
                        MID ( "A", 1, 10 ),
                        IF (
                            AND ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE] > 50, [Niveau_Moy_DPE] <= 91 ),
                            MID ( "B", 1, 10 ),
                            IF (
                                AND ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE] > 91, [Niveau_Moy_DPE] <= 151 ),
                                MID ( "C", 1, 10 ),
                                IF (
                                    AND ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE] > 151, [Niveau_Moy_DPE] <= 231 ),
                                    MID ( "D", 1, 10 ),
                                    IF (
                                        AND ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE] > 231, [Niveau_Moy_DPE] <= 331 ),
                                        MID ( "E", 1, 10 ),
                                        IF (
                                            AND ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE] > 331, [Niveau_Moy_DPE] <= 451 ),
                                            MID ( "F", 1, 10 ),
                                            IF (
                                                AND ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE] > 451, [Niveau_Moy_DPE] <= 531 ),
                                                MID ( "G", 1, 10 ),
                                                IF (
                                                    [Niveau_Moy_DPE] > 531,
                                                    MID ( "H", 1, 10 ),
                                                    MID ( [Niveau_Moy_DPE], 1, 20 )
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                "Moy_Niv_Moy_GES", [GES_MONTANT] / [Nombre immeuble],
                "Note_Moy_DPE",
                    IF (
                        AND ( [Niveau_Moy_GES] >= 0, [Niveau_Moy_GES] <= 5 ),
                        MID ( "A", 1, 10 ),
                        IF (
                            AND ( [Niveau_Moy_GES] > 5, [Niveau_Moy_GES] <= 11 ),
                            MID ( "B", 1, 10 ),
                            IF (
                                AND ( [Niveau_Moy_GES] > 11, [Niveau_Moy_GES] <= 21 ),
                                MID ( "C", 1, 10 ),
                                IF (
                                    AND ( [Niveau_Moy_GES] > 21, [Niveau_Moy_GES] <= 35 ),
                                    MID ( "D", 1, 10 ),
                                    IF (
                                        AND ( [Niveau_Moy_GES] > 35, [Niveau_Moy_GES] <= 51 ),
                                        MID ( "E", 1, 10 ),
                                        IF (
                                            AND ( [Niveau_Moy_GES] > 51, [Niveau_Moy_GES] <= 80 ),
                                            MID ( "F", 1, 10 ),
                                            IF (
                                                [Niveau_Moy_GES] > 80,
                                                MID ( "G", 1, 10 ),
                                                MID ( [Niveau_Moy_GES], 1, 20 )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
            ),
            [PERIODE_REP_ID],
            [AGENCE_ID],
            [IMMEUBLE_ID],
            [Libellé Immeuble],
            [nombre_Lot],
            [Nombre immeuble],
            [Regroupement 2],
            [IMMEUBLE_SURF],
            //[SURF_AUDITEE],
            [DPE_MONTANT],
            [DPE_INDIC],
            [GES_MONTANT],
            [GES_INDIC],
            [CODE_DPE],
            [Niveau_Moy_DPE],
            [CODE_GES],
            [Niveau_Moy_GES],
            [Donnée élémentaire4],
            [Note_Moy_DPE],
            "Total(IMMEUBLE_SURF)", SUMX ( CURRENTGROUP (), [IMMEUBLE_SURF] ),
            "Total(Nombre_Lot)", SUMX ( CURRENTGROUP (), [Nombre_Lot] ),
            "Total(SURF_AUDITEE)", SUMX ( CURRENTGROUP (), [SURF_AUDITEE] ),
            "Moyenne(CODE_DPE)", AVERAGEX ( CURRENTGROUP (), [GES_MONTANT] ),
            "Moyenne(DPE_MONTANT)", AVERAGEX ( CURRENTGROUP (), [DPE_MONTANT] ),
            "Moy_Niv_Moy_DPE", AVERAGEX ( CURRENTGROUP (), [Moy_Niv_Moy_DPE] ),
            "Moy_Niv_Moy_GES", AVERAGEX ( CURRENTGROUP (), [Moy_Niv_Moy_GES] )
        )
```

As stressed earlier I need to Add the column SURF_AUDITEE to the result but not group by it

Comment: Hi, can you provide a sample dataset and an output in tabular form?

Comment: Hello I edited my question and added a more thourough explaination and a screen shot of my result, Thnak you